# how to redirect the page in my link en php

Tags: php

I'm new programmer en PHP I would like  to redirect the page

when I select the link but I don't know what i'm doing wrong because when i select the link i can't see the content of the page but the path of  the browser it a true path.

this is my link:

```
<li><a href="category.php?catid=1">Literat</a></li>
```

but when i put

```
echo $_GET['catid'];  #en my page category.php  i don't see anything#
```

the page is empty.

i don't know how to make it work?

thank you very much

Comment: Try putting this at the top of your page: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Check your PHP error log, there may be a syntax error in the script.

Comment: What do you see if you `View > source` in your browser (really view the source, don't use inspect element)

Comment: Can you post `category.php` file code here ?

Answer (score -1):

You try:

Create php file test with name **test_get.php** with content:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   echo("First name: " . $_GET['firstname'] . "<br />\n");
   echo("Last name: " . $_GET['lastname'] . "<br />\n");
?>
```

Upload to your host and fill address like below:

```
http://your_host_domain/test_get.php?firstname=VNLIVES&lastname=.NET
```

If success you will see:

[image]

Else you see error report form PHP server.

Reference: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-get.html

Good Luck!

Comment: hy 

i try the test file and i see the same information.

i don't have any problem en redirect in my Browser because i see the true path.

Comment: thanks for our help i don't see any think about the content of the page what about category.php i have just echo $_GET['catid']; i put just echo "hello"; i can't see it